# SQL Server parameterized SELECT procedure returns no result, but returns records when set explicitly

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm having problems with the following procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Q2_05] (@Ch1 nvarchar, @Ch4 nvarchar, @globalOptionCode nvarchar)

AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SELECT [2_05].Ch1, [2_05].Ch4, [2_05].GlobalOption, [2_05].Part, [2_05].[Key]
    FROM [dbo.NV300Autostructure].[2_05]
    WHERE ((([2_05].Ch1)=@Ch1) AND (([2_05].Ch4)=@Ch4) AND (([2_05].GlobalOption)=@globalOptionCode));
END
```

when I execute it with the following parameters ('5', 'TH', '.') it returns no results, but in the process of elimination I found that modifying the conditions line and set [2_05].Ch4 explicitly to 'TH' like so:

```
    WHERE ((([2_05].Ch1)=@Ch1) AND (([2_05].Ch4)='TH') AND (([2_05].GlobalOption)=@globalOptionCode));
```

it returns a row of the database. Why is that happening?

Comment: Probably worth a read: [Bad habits to kick : declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length)

Comment: @GarethD can I still use this type of query if I'm not sure how long the parameter I will use (in that case it could be from 1 to 3 characters long) ?

Comment: If you don't know how long it will be use the maximum it could possibly be, if you don't know this just use `NVARCHAR(MAX)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not specifying a size for your `nvarchar` parameters. The default is 1 character.

So the procedure is testing for `[2_05].Ch4)='T'` when you use the parameters.

Comment: I didn't know it was necessary. How do I do it within SQL SMS (right-click on procedure -> execute)?

Also, I'm using Java to access this database, and calling the procedure using callable statements, eg.:
   { call dbo.Q2_05(?, ?, ?) }
and passing variables, is there a way to use the same method of calling them?

Comment: You don't need to change anything when you call the stored procedure. You need to update the procedure itself. `create procedure xx @Param nvarchar(**50**) ....`

Comment: @kacpr You should declare the size of the parameter in the stored procedure to the same as the column you are comparing against (`[2_05].Ch4`).